# error:a hook ('orm') failed to load when lifting sails app using Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js

I am trying to connect my project wigh Sails.js to Redis, but when I try to lift it, I have an error of READONLY,

the whole error is the next:

```
error: A hook ('orm') failed to load!
error: Error: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.
    at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/home/victor/Downloads/gestamp-desarrollo/gestamp-desarrollo/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/hiredis.js:30:33)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/home/victor/Downloads/gestamp-desarrollo/gestamp-desarrollo/node_modules/redis/index.js:547:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/victor/Downloads/gestamp-desarrollo/gestamp-desarrollo/node_modules/redis/index.js:102:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21) [Error: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.]
error: Error: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.
    at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/home/victor/Downloads/gestamp-desarrollo/gestamp-desarrollo/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/hiredis.js:30:33)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/home/victor/Downloads/gestamp-desarrollo/gestamp-desarrollo/node_modules/redis/index.js:547:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/victor/Downloads/gestamp-desarrollo/gestamp-desarrollo/node_modules/redis/index.js:102:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21) [Error: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.]
```

The Sails.js version is 0.10.5

My connections.js is

```
  redis: {
    adapter: 'sails-redis',
    port: 6379,
    host: '10.250.201.3',
//    host: 'localhost',
    password: null,
    database: 2,
    options: {

      // low-level configuration
      // (redis driver options)
      parser: 'hiredis',
      return_buffers: false,
      detect_buffers: false,
      socket_nodelay: true,
      no_ready_check: false,
      enable_offline_queue: true
    }
  },
```

And my model is:

```
module.exports = {
    schema: false,
    connection: 'redis'
};
```

Comment: My wild guess would be that 10.250.201.3 is running a read-only Redis slave on port 6379...

Comment: `You can't write against a read only slave.`. I think the error is pretty clear...

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer. 

But now I have another question, Is there a way to connect my application to Redis with an only read Slave?

Comment: Hi Victor! I currently have the same issue. Did you get solve the problem ?

Comment: @VictorGarcia please help me